# Vue js Image force download not working by using anchor tag

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, laravel-5

I am using Laravel with vue js. I need to download an image forcefully on browser but it's now working for me.

```
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = 'image/ab.jpg';
link.download = 'Download.jpg';
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();
document.body.removeChild(link);
```

This is working for simple javascript but for vue js, it's not working. Its simply opening image URL in the browser.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53775165/4051471)

Answer (score 0):

You sure your code working for simple javascript?

The download attribute is subject to the same-origin policy.